# Combining 3 for loops into 1 in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, equations

I have this section of code which is working fine but i don't like the way i have implemented those 3 separate for loops. Can anyone suggest to me that how can i merge them together to make it even more efficient and compact ? Thank you

```
clear variables;
close all;
clc;

ilambda=5;
mu=2;

n=2;
jmax=n+1;
P= sym('P',[jmax,jmax]);

for j1 = 1:jmax
        for j2 = 2:jmax-1
            [c1,c2,c3,c4,c5]=coefficients(ilambda,mu,j1,j2);    
            if j1<jmax
                E(j1, j2) = c1*P(j1, j2) - c2 * P(j1+1, j2) - c3 * P(j1, j2+1) - c4 * P(j1, j2-1);
            else
                E(j1, j2) = c1 * P(j1, j2) - c3 * P(j1, j2+1) - c4 * P(j1, j2-1);
            end

        end
end

    j2=1;
    for j1=1:jmax;
        [c1,c2,c3,c4,c5]=coefficients(ilambda,mu,j1,j2);    
        if (j1<jmax)
            E(j1, j2) = c1*P(j1, j2) - c2 * P(j1+1, j2) - c3 * P(j1, j2+1);
        else
            E(j1, j2) = c1*P(j1, j2) - c3 * P(j1, j2+1);
        end
    end


    j2=jmax;
    for j1=1:jmax;
        [c1,c2,c3,c4,c5]=coefficients(ilambda,mu,j1,j2); 
        if (j1==1)
            E(j1, j2) = c1*P(j1, j2) - c2 * P(j1+1, j2) - c4 * P(j1, j2-1);
        elseif (j1==jmax)
            c1=((j1-1)*mu)+((j2-1)*mu);
            E(j1, j2) = c1 * P(j1, j2) - c4 * P(j1, j2-1) - c5 * P(j1-1, j2);
        else
            E(j1, j2) = c1*P(j1, j2) - c2 * P(j1+1, j2)- c4 * P(j1, j2-1)- c5 * P(j1-1, j2);
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `j1` will always go from `1` to `jmax`, it should not be that hard.
What you're basically doing now is working on the inner part of the matrix, then on the first column and then on the last column, all rows included (i.e. you build your matrix by columns).
You can instead build your matrix by rows (with index `j1`) and then build separately the columns according to `j2` as follows:

```
for j1 = 1:jmax

    % set j2 at 1 and work on the first column
    j2=1;
    [c1,c2,c3,c4,c5]=coefficients(ilambda,mu,j1,j2);
    if (j1<jmax)
        E(j1, j2) = c1*P(j1, j2) - c2 * P(j1+1, j2) - c3 * P(j1, j2+1);
    else
        E(j1, j2) = c1*P(j1, j2) - c3 * P(j1, j2+1);
    end

    % set j2 as variable in for loop
    for j2 = 2:jmax-1
        [c1,c2,c3,c4,c5]=coefficients(ilambda,mu,j1,j2);
        if j1<jmax
            E(j1, j2) = c1*P(j1, j2) - c2 * P(j1+1, j2) - c3 * P(j1, j2+1) - c4 * P(j1, j2-1);
        else
            E(j1, j2) = c1 * P(j1, j2) - c3 * P(j1, j2+1) - c4 * P(j1, j2-1);
        end
    end

    % finally set j2 as jmax and work on the last column
    j2=jmax;
    if (j1==1)
        E(j1, j2) = c1*P(j1, j2) - c2 * P(j1+1, j2) - c4 * P(j1, j2-1);
    elseif (j1==jmax)
        c1=((j1-1)*mu)+((j2-1)*mu);
        E(j1, j2) = c1 * P(j1, j2) - c4 * P(j1, j2-1) - c5 * P(j1-1, j2);
    else
        E(j1, j2) = c1*P(j1, j2) - c2 * P(j1+1, j2)- c4 * P(j1, j2-1)- c5 * P(j1-1, j2);
    end

% basically now you have completed the j1-th row
% the following loop will work in the very same way, that is:
% working on the j1-st row and then working separately on the 1st
% column, then on the inner columns and then on the last column.
end
```

Another (very elegant, in my opinion) approach is by using the `switch/case`. In this case the pseudocode will be something like

```
for j1=1:jmax
    for j2=1:jmax
        switch j2
            case 1 
            % enter here what to do if j2==1
            case jmax
            % enter here what to do if j2==jmax
            otherwise
            % enter here what to do if j2 is between 2 and jmax-1
        end
    end
end
```

*Note*: I tried with arbitrary values for coefficients c1...c5, I hope this(these) solution(s) work(s) as well with your `coefficients()` function.

Comment: I am selecting the switch case option. Seems more elegant to me as well. Thank you so much.